# Gridline formatting

Tags: d3.js

If I add this style (.style("opacity", .2) to a rectangle the gridlines appear in front of the rectangle, in this example http://bl.ocks.org/bunkat/1962173.  Is there a way to bring shape to front or send gridline back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a jsfiddle to play with dom order and `opacity`:
http://jsfiddle.net/laurieskelly/9jr65/

If you back the shapes with identical shapes of the background color, the grid lines will not show through.

Simpler solution: do the shapes really need to be transparent?

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle -nice work.  I've also got text inside the shape  so will look for another option.  Is it possible to format horizontal grid lines and leave the vertical lines?  This code changes all:  grid = main.selectAll('line')
             .style("stroke-dasharray", ("3, 3"))
             .style("stroke-opacity", 0.2);

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, could you clarify?

Answer (score 1):

The elements in an SVG are displayed in the order in which they are added to the DOM. That is, anything you want displayed on top of everything else should be added last. In your case, you need to add the rectangle after adding the grid lines.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that and it works with rect opacity = 1 but with opacity = 0.2 the gridlines show through!

Comment: Well yes, if the elements in front are transparent, the elements behind them will show through.